# Unable to search for a specific date inside mongodb using MongoDB Compass

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I have the following document entry:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5f0f876df0127d7d1612139c"
    },
    "stream": [{
        "$numberLong": "1594638000000"
    }, 8213.9, 8224, 8213.8, 8224, 18.1126896],
    "asset": "BTC/EUR",
    "timeframe": "5m",
    "date": {
        "$date": "2020-07-13T11:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

No matter what I have tried, I'm not able to return this specific entry when I search for the date.

I tried:

```
{"date":{"$date":new Date("2020-07-13T10:55:00.000+00:00")}}

{"date":{"$date":ISODate("2020-07-13T10:55:00.000Z")}}
```

No success.

Answer (score 1):

The correct query was:

```
{"date":ISODate("2020-07-13T12:25:00Z")}
```

Also there is some nasty bug in Compass.